# ClassNotFoundException jdbc-odbc connection

Tags: java

Using `MySQL ODBC 5.3` Unicode Driver  how to connect java and odbc?
I am using `Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")`
and getting `ClassNotFoundException` how to resolve this?

Comment: Check the jar which are you using.

Comment: Can you please paste  the stack trace ?

Comment: If you are using Java 8: the `JdbcOdbcDriver` has been removed. Why don't you use the MySQL JDBC driver (Connector/J) instead?

Comment: Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428747/classnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-accdb-file-via-jdbc-odbc-in-ja?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the java connector for MySQL from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j. and then load it as `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar file to your projects in build path
And copy the file to WEB-INF/lib directory